# dice roll game stuck in a loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program for a game of pig where there user enters a point total to play for and then takes turns with a computer player until one player reaches the point total. For the human turn the player rolls and if they roll 2-6 then they can use r to roll again or h to hold. when hold is selected it adds up the total points and goes to the next turn. If 1 is rolled then they get 0 points for the round and it goes to the computers turn. For some reason when I select h to hold it just keeps going and when it does end the points don't get added up. Not sure how to fix this
any help would be appericated

```cs
static int pigRoll()
{    
    Random random = new Random();
    int die1 = 0;
    die1 = random.Next(1, 6);
    Console.WriteLine($"You rolled {die1}");
    return die1;
}

static double humanTurn()
{
    double pointTotal = 0;
    string gameSelect = null;
    var pigDiceRoll = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("It's your turn");
    do
    {
         pigDiceRoll = pigRoll();
         if (pigDiceRoll != 1)
         {
              Console.WriteLine("r to roll or h to hold (r/h)");
              gameSelect = Console.ReadLine();
              pointTotal = pointTotal + pigDiceRoll;
         }
         else if(pigDiceRoll ==1)
         {
              pointTotal = 0;
         }
    } while (gameSelect != "r" || pigDiceRoll != 1);
    Console.WriteLine($"Your turn point total is {pointTotal}");
    return pointTotal;
}
```

Comment: if i read it right, i think your `while` should be `gameSelect == "r"`

Comment: Please note that `random.Next(1, 6)` only produces values from `1` to `5`. The second parameter is an **exclusive** upper-bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while statement should read:

```
while (gameSelect == "r" && pigDiceRoll != 1)
```

This translates to keep looping while the user wants to roll again and they didn't roll a 1.

Alternatively you could use:

```
while (!(gameSelect != "r" || pigDiceRoll == 1))
```

Both are logically the same, but the first is probably easier to read.